# How to change icon of Extension Entity in Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2016 Online?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created custom entities. I have set it in Sales. So, user can open it and use it. Ex. I have created new entity `Purchase Order` & `Purchase Order Invoice`. It shows default icon(Green) of CRM.

I want to change that icon and set my icon. Can anybody suggest me how to change the icon of Entity?
Please review following screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer. It looks pretty easy and simple : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/213172

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing SiteMap xml manually there is an 'Icon' attribute in 'Subarea' node or if you are using XrmToolBox there is also an 'Icon' field that you cen set to your web resource.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is also a good answer: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/213172